# Get last posted photos from facebook graph

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I see that FQL is deprecated?

We now use the Graph API and with url .

What I want is to get all the latest pictures of my friends and **NOT** from pages or other stuff.

If I use:

> me/home/?filter=app_2305272732

will I also get back pictures from pages and more.

How can I ONLY get pictures of friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you would need to use the `read_stream` permission to get friend postings in the stream of the authorized user, and since friend permissions are gone, there is no way to achieve this. You will not get `read_stream` approved: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Information about the friend permissions are in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You can only get the latest photos and posts of the authorized user by authorizing him with the `user_status` permissions and using `/me/statuses`.

Comment: So you are saying is that you no longer get out about any information from friends of the authorized user, if not the friend of the authorized user also authorized to the app? This makes almost Facebook API useless to very much!

Comment: that is what i am saying. although, i disagree that it makes the api useless, it just protects the privacy of users who don´t use your app.

Comment: How do some apps and then find friends of mine who are most active and profile photo , for example ! They do  NOT use the app !

Comment: most likely they are using an old app created before april 2014, so they can still use v1.0 of the api - but it will stop working for them after april 2015. please read the changelog, it´s all in there. friend permissions are gone, that is a fact.

Comment: And also bounty :D 100+ Thank you for taking the time to write a good answer !